# How to set localappdata path properly, not showing the full path(Path.Combine & Environment.GetFolderPath)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to Path.Combine, but having highlighted string(appdatapath), helper say's that "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property'MySuperAPP.appdatapath' "

the code is :

```
string appdatapath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

string path = Path.Combine(appdatapath, "second/part/of/folderpath");
```

what i want is:
string path = "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Some/Dir/"

what i tried :

```
string static appdatapath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

string static path = Path.Combine(appdatapath,"second/part/of/folderpath").ToString;
```

and

```
public static string GetMyLocalAppDir()
        {
            return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData).ToString();
        }
string path = Path.Combine(GetMyLocalAppDir(),"second/part/of/folderpath").ToString;
```

i think the variants that i'm tried may be wrong..)
need your advice) thank's!)

Comment: Make "appdatapath" also static. A static variable can not contain dynamic references.

Comment: when i'm declare it like "string static appdatapath' it also stay's highlighted and helper say's the same...
missing something but can't figure it out what..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `initialize` a field (this mean: when you provide a dynamic field with a value at `runtime`) it must be a `static` value.
Therefore you must declare "appdatapath" as `static`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static string appdatapath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

    private (static) string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(appdatapath, "second/part/of/folderpath"); //make this static if you want that this field can't be changed.
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Also make sure your declaration is in the right order:

`public or private` `static or not` `type e.g. string` `name of variable`

Finaly: if you have more directory's to combine, put eacht part separately:

```
Path.Combine(appdatapath, "second", "part", "of", "folderpath")
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me) i'm already figure it out..
"need to make some coffee")

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void Read_bootup3_file()
    {
        qq = 0;
        string downloadz2;

        string fileNameSDcard = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "download.txt");
        string CurrentContents;
        CurrentContents = fileNameSDcard;
//CurrentContents = File.ReadAllText(fileNameSDcard);
        File.WriteAllText(fileNameSDcard, CurrentContents);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileNameSDcard))
        {
            downloadz2 = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
//downloadz = downloadz2.ToCharArray();

        qq = 0;
        for (leep = 0; leep <= lotsize; leep++)
        {
            for (lep = 0; lep <= 20; lep++)
            {
                Tester.garage_array_database[lep, leep] = downloadz[qq].ToString();
                qq++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can not find "download.txt" the rest of the project works.                   declare public static char[] downloadz = new char[210000];

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).